# Matplotlib tex-macro in description

Tags: python, matplotlib, pgf

I'm using `matplotlib` to generate `pgf` files.
Based on those, I use standalone `tex` files which only include necessary settings and the afore-built `pgf`s.
In this scenario, I'm getting errors when using custom tex-macros for descriptions in my plot files.

Here an example `pgf` generator:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    "pgf.preamble": [
        #r"\newcommand{\foo}{foo}",
        r"\usepackage{import}",
        r'\subimport{./}{foo.tex}'
    ]
})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,2.5))
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.xlabel(r'\foo{}')
plt.savefig('foo.pgf')
```

that can be used in a dir with the following `foo.tex` file:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
```

Running this results in the following error:

```
ValueError: Error processing '\foo{}'
LaTeX Output:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ....000000}{12.000000}\selectfont \foo
                                                  {}
<*> ...ze{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont \foo{}}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Please note, that this is an error generated by `matplotlib` and **not** of compiling my standalone files.
Also note, that the error goes away when the `\foo` macro is provided as part of the `pgf.preamble`
(the line commented out) instead.
I checked the `pgf` produced by this variant and indeed it uses `\foo{}`.

I'm having trouble narrowing the problem further down.
Here my concrete questions:

1. Why does `matplotlib` invoke `pdflatex` at all?
   I'm generating `pgf` output and thus `pdflatex` should not be necessary.
   (For the reference: I `strace`d the script above and indeed know that `pdflatex` is being called.)
2. Is there a way of preserving the temporary file that `matplotlib` tries to compile?
   The error references `texput.log` by (of course) that file doesn't exist afterwards.
3. Why can't I use a macro in a label which is provided in another tex file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Including `tex`-files in the `pgf.preamble` of `matplotlib` requires absolute paths.

---

For the future, I recommend the following `pdflatex` "replacement script" for purposes of debugging:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MAIN=/usr/bin/pdflatex
cat /dev/stdin | tee /some/abs/path/to/dbg.tex | "${MAIN}" "${@}"
```

Make sure to save it as `pdflatex`, make sure it's executable, make sure `/usr/bin/pdflatex` is your actual `pdflatex` and ensure this wrapper is found first in yout `PATH` (cf. `which pdflatex`).
When running the `python` generator, we preserve the final `tex` input in the `dbg.tex`.
That answers (2).

Considering the output, we see:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{import}
\subimport{./}{foo.tex}

\begin{document}
text $math \mu$
\typeout{pgf_backend_query_start}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont lp}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 0}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 1}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 2}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 3}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont 4}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
\sbox0{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont \foo{}}
\typeout{\the\wd0,\the\ht0,\the\dp0}
```

I don't know what that should be useful for. 
But I'm guessing `matplotlib` is trying to adjust the font-setup for which it tries compiling this "test" document.
That (sort of) answers (1).

Now the conclusion (obvious in hindsight):
`matplotlib` compiles this sample document in a temporary directory.
Clearly there is no `foo.tex` available in this directory, so the `subimport` fails.
From that point onwards it is obvious that `\foo` will not be available.

Though not the cleanest solution, 
this can be fixed by including `foo.tex` via an absolute path.
Working python generator to finally answer (3):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import pathlib

mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage{import}",
        f'\subimport{{{pathlib.Path.cwd().resolve()}/}}{{foo.tex}}']
})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,2.5))
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.xlabel(r'\foo{}')
plt.savefig('foo.pgf')
```

(I use `python3` and `pathlib`. 
For `python2` we would rather fall back to [os.getcwd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).)